# running a py loop in RStudio with in a .py file

Tags: python, loops, rstudio, reticulate

I have .py file open in RStudio and would like to run a loop such as this..

```
lst = ["2001","2004","2006","2008","2011","2013","2016","2019"]

for i in lst:   print "hello " + i
```

However, when I run the loop (ctrl+enter), in the console it simply gives the '...' but nothing runs.

[image]

Then if I type 'exit' it will print the results

[image]

Is there a way to run a loop without needing to type exit in the console?

Comment: It prints `...` because it doesn't know if you want to put more lines of code inside the loop body.  Entering a blank line (i.e. just press Enter) signals that the loop body is complete.

Comment: Oh, wow that was easy.